# PhoneGap not firing deviceready on Android 4.2

Tags: android, events, cordova

I created an application with the create.bat on windows and compiled it with ADT and the latest SDK.

It launches and displays the cordova display but it doesnt fire the deviceready event as it keeps saying "connecting to device". The same applies for the emulator. It works when I change the OS to 4.0 for the emulator though.

Is this normal because 4.2 has just been released and I have to wait for an update ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Mac. However, I think I saw a similar issue last week when I was helping a friend get setup. I got him running on a 4.0 emulator instead. I will dig out my PC on Monday to try it out.

Comment: Ah hi, I'm the same guy from the google groups. I got it working on an emulator with 4.0 but I need it to work on my Nexus 7 device with 4.2. I tried almost everything and looked at the logcat output. The deviceready event never appears.

Comment: can you provide some code of your index.html???

Comment: @Dilberted I'm using the default html by cordova.

Comment: There does seem to be some sort of issue with 4.2 - I just deployed my app to a new nexus 7 (4.1.1), and it was working fine until I installed the system update. If you aren't comfortable digging around in the cordova internals you'll probably need to wait for someone who is to make an update.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm new to Java and the guts of an Android application. I hope it's not too difficult to fix.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's 1 am and I finally have my app running again. Android 4.2 includes some apparently security related changes to webView.addJavascriptInterface, which stops the default bridge mode from working.

I expect there will be a better fix in the next version, but if you need a quick fix, try this  update to CordovaWebView.exposeJsInterface

```
private void exposeJsInterface() {
    int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    boolean isHoneycomb = (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2);
    if (isHoneycomb || (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.");
        // Bug being that Java Strings do not get converted to JS strings automatically.
        // This isn't hard to work-around on the JS side, but it's easier to just
        // use the prompt bridge instead.
        return;            
    } else if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("unknown")) {
        // addJavascriptInterface crashes on the 2.3 emulator.
        Log.i(TAG, "Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge callback due to a bug on the 2.3 emulator");
        return;

    } else if (SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {            
        Log.i(TAG, "Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge callback for 4.2");
        return;


    }
    this.addJavascriptInterface(exposedJsApi, "_cordovaNative");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Here is the working cordova.jar to save some peoples time: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14645664/cordova-2.2.0.jar

Comment: You guys are AMAZZIN! Thank you!

Comment: I've spent hours on this, what a life saver

Comment: Tom Clarkson and @elias94xx thanks a lot guys!!! I had the whole day an error --Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'-- just because the deviceReady function was not fired and I didn't notice that. Big thumbs up!!

Answer (score 29):

I had teh same problem on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.2
but it works when I change the AndroidManifest targetSdkVersion to "16"

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />   (Before it was ="17")
```

I hope this works for someone.

Diego

Comment: Good enough for my purposes, and much easier that the other answer.

Comment: One character fix! Worked for me +1

Comment: I'm with Phonegap 2.8.1 now and still experience this issues. Soooo sh*ttty! And change the target doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 9):

In my case auto generated index.html was referring to **phonegap.js**

so instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

I put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: The same issue happened for me. It seems that, I created the project using "phonegap create", not "cordova create"

Comment: If you read warning notes during build process you will notice message which will advice you to use cordova.js.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is fixed in [Phonegap 2.3.0](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tree/2.3.0).

Also encountered this problem on Android 4.2, my project was using Phonegap 2.2.

Updated following this [simple upgrade procedure](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android) - problem solved.

Hence, after the upgrade to 2.3.0, setting `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` is ok again.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this is that your cordova-2.3.0.jar might not match cordova-2.3.0.js file version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing any error in js file (Index.js).

you must make sure that you javascript have not any errors.