# PhoneGap Android Emulator Black Screen on Windows 7

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am following the Phonegap Android getting started guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

After a lot of fiddling, I have got everything running with the following versions:
Phonegap 2.4
Android SDK tools 21.1
Android SDK platform tools 16.0.1
Android SDK Platform 4.2

When I run the app in the emulator (via Eclipse), it launches but shows the flashing Android logo. If I right-click the project and run again, the console shows the app is installing and launched. However, the android logo remains.

Console log:

```
[2013-02-21 02:27:16 - testapp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-02-21 02:28:04 - testapp] ------------------------------
[2013-02-21 02:28:04 - testapp] Android Launch!
[2013-02-21 02:28:04 - testapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-21 02:28:04 - testapp] Performing com.rb.testapp.testapp activity launch
[2013-02-21 02:28:05 - testapp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'test'
[2013-02-21 02:28:05 - testapp] Uploading testapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-02-21 02:28:45 - testapp] Installing testapp.apk...
[2013-02-21 02:29:04 - testapp] Success!
[2013-02-21 02:29:05 - testapp] Starting activity com.rb.testapp.testapp on device emulator-5554
```

If I run the app from the command line /cordova/run.bat. The Emulator launches with a blank screen. The console reports the app is installed and launching.

I'm guessing there's a problem with the version of the emulator i'm running. My CPU does not support virtualisation. Is there any way to get this running?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed this myself by installing the Android SDK 4.0 platform and using this for my emulator. Aparrently there is a fix for this (although I haven't tried this): [PhoneGap not firing deviceready on Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433656/phonegap-not-firing-deviceready-on-android-4-2)

I have documented my setup process here: http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/installing-android-4-2-sdk-and-phonegap-2-4-0-on-windows-7/